# misalignment of pageblock section items

Tags: apex, visualforce

In pageblock there is apex repeat of pageblock section.The items in the page block section are not aligned properly. how to fix this.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: You'd better post the relevant Visualforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `<apex:panelGrid>` as explained in this answer:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000097NXIAY

> if you set the columnClasses property of the panelGrid you can then
>   just set the widths of each column (you'll need a column for the label
>   and the field).   e.g.

```
<style>
    .tableStyle {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px 0px; }
    .colStyle1 { width: 16.5%; padding: 3px 0 5px 0;    text-align:right;}
    .colStyle2 { width: 10%;   padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;                  }
    .colStyle3 { width: 10%;   padding: 5px 0;          text-align:right;}
    .colStyle4 { width: 21%;   padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;                  }
    .colStyle5 { width: 10%;   padding: 5px 0;          text-align:right;}
    .colStyle6 { width: 32%;   padding: 5px 0 4px 20px;                  }
    .rowstyle { border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#E8E8E8 }
</style>

<apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Allowances" columns="1" id="allowances">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="6" border="0" styleClass="tableStyle" width="100%" columnClasses="colStyle1,colStyle2,colStyle3,colStyle4,colStyle5,colStyle6" rowClasses="rowstyle">
```

Comment: It worked. All the fields are aligned perfectly.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the `dataStyle` or `dataStyleClass` attributes on the `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem />` elements to coerce that column to be consistently wider.

[apex:pageBlockSectionItem documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm)

Your tag might look like this for that third column:

`<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:20%;">`

This would instruct the browser that you want the "data" cell to the right (not the label cell to the left) to render as 20% of the width of the entire table that it is within. This may be too large of a percentage, so adjust as necessary.